# Symbol's value as variable is void: helm-map

Tags: helm

Windows 10, Emacs 25.1

In my init.el

```
(define-key helm-map (kbd "<tab>") 'helm-execute-persistent-action)
```

But on start Emacs I get error:

```
Symbol's value as variable is void: helm-map
```

Comment: That variable would only be defined after `helm` is loaded. You'd need to either `require` it, or wrap that code in `with-eval-after-load`.

Comment: @wvxvw This question is also addressed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15995754/for-emacs-how-to-bind-keys-only-in-certain-action. There they use `helm-find-files-map`.

Comment: Apparently their earlier duplicate question taught them nothing.  This should be closed.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error:

```
variable fails due to missing definition of "helm-bookmark-map"
```

You can remove the helm and force the reinstall. (so basically remove the helm file/folder under elpa)

Remove .emacs.d/elpa/helm-* and restart emacs? This should force a reinstall of helm with the pinned version.

This worked for me in spacemacs.